# How to get lightning-table column width in an aura wrapped LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-datatable

I have a LWC that is wrapped in an aura component.  I have been spinning my wheels for a few days on trying to access the attributes of the `lightning-datatable` after it's been loaded, specifically the columns and their width.

I am trying to follow the various SFDC docs on lifecycle hooks and running code when a component renders, as well as the lwc-recipes on Github. But I'm still running into dead ends because of my lack of knowledge.

My code so far is:

```
renderedCallback() {
    if(!this._hasRendered) {
        this._ldtResults = this.template.querySelector('lightning-datatable');
        console.log('all new here: ' + this._ldtResults);
    }
}
```

How do I see what attributes are available and then drill down from there? Or are there any?

I have been playing around with trying to see if I can get to the attributes, so I have tried this line and then writing that to the console, but it returns 0 (zero):

```
this._ldtResults = this.template.querySelector('lightning-datatable').attributes.length;
```

I am lost as to what to try/google for my next steps. I'm just getting into the dev side of stuff, so I am eager to learn best practices. Or if you think I missed some documentation, then please let me know.

Comment: Components are essentially black boxes that expose values via @api. You won't be able to see anything that you're not explicitly allowed to see, including the internal structure of the component's DOM. Whatever you're trying to do, you'll need to find an alternative method.

Comment: Gotcha.  Thanks for the response.